# Включение/отключение select по переменной в контроллере

Tags: mvc, razor

Есть код:

```
@{ string tempClass = ViewBag.IsCreate ? "enabled" : " disabled";}
<div class="text-primary h3 text-left col-2 pl-0">Скидка</div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupDiscount, new SelectList(GroupsDiscount, "Key", "Value"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control selectedDiscountGroup col-md-10", @disabled=tempClass })
```

Как мне если `ViewBag.IsCreate` = true убрать вообще аттрибут `disabled`? иначе ничего не работает

Comment: helper сделай и по условию добавляй или не добавляй атрибут disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupDiscount, new SelectList(GroupsDiscount, "Key", "Value"),  ViewBag.IsCreate ? new { @class = "form-control selectedDiscountGroup col-md-10"} as object: new { @class = "form-control selectedDiscountGroup col-md-10", @disabled = "disabled" } as object)
```

Comment: спасибо, как то не подумал за такую форму